# Error: Failed downloading the Cypress binary

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, cypress, vercel

I am using Nextjs and Vercel to deploy my website. Cypress was working fine yesterday. But today when Vercel runs the build I get the following error:

[image: error]

I noticed that vercel was installing Cypress version 6.9.0 whereas I had 6.8.0 in my `package.json` file.

[image: update cypress]

So I updated to version to 6.9.0 but I still get the same error. Why is this suddenly happening?

My `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env API_URL=http://localhost:1337 next dev",
    "public-dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.1.3",
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.35.0",
    "@blueprintjs/datetime": "^3.19.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.5.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.4",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "10.0.2",
    "next-with-apollo": "^5.1.0",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.3.8",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.10.6",
    "react-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.2.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.2.1",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-localization": "^1.0.15",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.13",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "swiper": "^6.3.5",
    "swr": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "cypress": "^6.9.0",
    "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.4.2",
    "eslint": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: You had `^6.8.0` in your package file, which means 6.8.0 <= version < 7.0.0, so `6.9.0` was included. But you should just be running `npm install` in your production environment, use `npm ci` so the lockfile is used and you get consistent builds.

Comment: Is this happening every time you push? Or was it only on one build?

Comment: @leerob it happened every time I pushed yesterday, but today the Cypress team removed 6.9.0 so everything is fine now. I will accept my answer below tomorrow when stackoverflow allows me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress team published 6.9.0 by mistake, really the version is 7.0.0 and they will remove 6.9.0:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15797